# how to export img alt with IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have just started using Google sheet's "IMPORTXML" to extract webpage data for my project.
im stuck when im trying to extract alt image list from the below page:

```
<div class="StoreLogo">
            <img id="" class=" lazyloaded" data-src="https://img.zap.co.il/pics/imgs/nsite/newui/newssite-185.gif" src="https://img.zap.co.il/pics/imgs/nsite/newui/newssite-185.gif" alt="dailypro" style="border-width:0px;">        
             <div class="CityName">
           </div>
        </div>
```

im trying to extract out the alt contains "dailypro" by the following formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.zap.co.il/model.aspx?modelid=1031595","//img[@class='lazyloaded']/@alt")
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. When using `IMPORTXML`, always View Source first as this is what it parses. Here, you will see that all the `img` tags have a "Logo lazyload" instead of  `lazyloaded`.
2. `IMPORTXML` doesn't see classes the same way that your browser does with HTML. You have to match the whole string for equality.

Thus, use this:

```
=IMPORTXML(
    "https://www.zap.co.il/model.aspx?modelid=1031595",
    "//img[@class='Logo lazyload']/@alt"
)
```